# Make an image open a modal on click?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Images are in `<div>` but when one of them are clicked a separate modal appear displaying information of div which one has been clicked.Modals have id or class like modal4
**This is my attempt:**

```
<image type="image" src="Images/Drake.jpg"  data-target="modal" data-toggle="#modal4" style="width:130px;height:140px;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:10px"/> </a>
```

Here's my modal code:

```
 <div class="modal" id="Modal4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Aubrey Drake "Drizzy" Graham</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap it in an <a href="#" data-target="modal" data-toggle="#examplemodal4"><image....

Comment: @pelle Could you edit my code to show what it should look like please? I'm a little confused as to how it would look.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: The code that you showed does not demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Not sure how you expect anyone to help you with this when you haven't shown us any of your existing HTML, CSS or JS

Comment: You are using Bootstrap, not only HTML + CSS. Please post correct informations if you want help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be because you are referring to modal id in all lower cases in you image tag while the actual modal id has an upper case **M**?

In img tag:
`data-toggle="#modal4"`

In modal declaration:
`id="Modal4"`

match cases everywhere to be sure.

Comment: @Harry How can it work? By the document of boostrap `data-toggle` have to be `modal` and `data-target` should be `#Modal4`.

Comment: I also added in the # myself but it was a simple case issue which was pointed out by the contributor

Answer (score 1):

Your `data-target` should be equal `#Modal4` and your `data-toggle` should be equal `modal`

```
data-target="#Modal4" data-toggle="modal"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<image src="https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/extension/isAllowedAccess/sample-128.png" data-target="#Modal4" data-toggle="modal" style="width:130px;height:140px;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:10px"/></a>
 
<div class="modal" id="Modal4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Aubrey Drake "Drizzy" Graham</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          SOMETHING
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it in a button or in :

```css
   <button type="button" class="btn  btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal4">
            <image type="image" src="images/windows-photo.jpg"  style="width:130px;height:140px;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:10px" />   
      </button>
    <a href="#"   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal4">
        <image type="image" src="images/windows-photo.jpg" style="width:130px;height:140px;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:10px" />
    </a>
```